# Population Estimation using Power-Law Inter-arrival Times

Tags: probability, statistics, queueing-theory

I am wondering if the community could give me some pointers on how to solve the following problem. I feel as if I am missing a key link and so I am having some challenges making some headway. Any Assistance would be greatly appreciated. Here we go!

There are $N$ fishermen on a lake with a fixed, yet unknown, number of fish in the lake. Each fisherman fishes at the same time and for a length of time $T$. When a fisherman catches a fish, the fisherman annotates the time when the fish was caught. There is no catch and release.

At the end of the fishing period, a person collects all times, sorts them and computes the inter-catch (inter-arrival) times. He notes that they are power-law distributed according to

\begin{equation}
\frac{\beta \alpha^\beta}{x^{1+\alpha}} I_{[\alpha,\infty)}(x)
\end{equation}

where $I_{[\alpha,\infty)}(x)$ represents that indicator function, or domain, where the distribution is defined.

With this setup, is it possible to estimate the population of fish within the lake?

Comment: Given any IID inter-arrival times $W_i$, the arrival times $T_n=W_1+\dotsc +W_n$ can be used to form a counting process by defining $N_t=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{T_n \leq t}$ which counts the number of fish caught by a single fisherman by time $t$. Repeating this for all $N$ fisherman will give a lower bound on the total population (since you cannot catch anymore than the total) but I don’t see how to study the unknown population directly from what is known.

Comment: The statement looks weird. For one thing : where do $N$ and $T$ enter ? Further, if "there is no catch and release" then the different $x$ would not have the same distribution...

Comment: If there is catch-and-release, the population of fish would remain constant, so wouldn't the inter-arrival time be IID and perhaps normally distributed?  I thought the power-law comes from the fact there is a finite number of fish, and the number "meaningfully" decreases during the experiment, s.t. it becomes "noticeably" harder to catch a fish (longer inter-arrival times) as the experiment goes on and fishes get removed.

Comment: @leonbloy - I suspect you would require $N$ and $T$ for the queueing system setup. Since I am not entirely sure what it would take to formulate this problem correctly I introduced those variables to ensure people don't say I have provided too little information for an adequate setup.

Comment: @antkam - I think you are on the right track with your statement. That's about as far as I got through. Thre is no catch-and-release so it is like trying to pull a certain color ball from an urn with two different colors where one color represents "catching fish" and the other represents "not catching fish". Each pick is done at a constant interval and then you keep track of when you pick a ball of the correct color. At the end, you find the interarrival times and then go from there... Not sure if this would work but to me that would make sense. Thoughts?

Comment: It is probably reasonable to model fish catching as a Poisson process (the limit to your balls and urn model), but then the rate $\lambda$ would intuitively be proportional to the number of fish $F$ still left in the lake, and the expected inter-arrival time would be $\propto 1/\lambda \propto 1/F$.  I.e. suppose there were $F_0$ fish to start with, then the expected inter-arrival times would be $\propto 1/F_0, 1/(F_0-1), 1/(F_0 -2)$ etc as each fish gets caught.  I can't quite see how this (plus randomization of Poisson) would fit your specific form of power law, except very approximately.